# How does Debian (or OSs in general) handle opening of multiple instances of a program?

Tags: debian, process, scheduling

How does the OS handle it if I were to open up 10 terminal windows? Does it use multi-threading, or multi-processing? Or is there some other concept that I am yet not aware of? And if I were to run a Python script on all 10 of them, how would they run with GIL? Would they run in multiple-processing until all the cores (8 in my case) in the CPU are running Python, then switch to multi-threading with concurrency? Also, where can I read more on this?

Comment: Mainly the OS doesn't care. Two instances of the same program are treated just like two different programs. If there is some interference, it is caused by the program, not by the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can depend of the terminal application. You can launch multiple `xterm` terminals, then you have 1 process per terminal. With a terminal which support multiple tabs, it can be implemented with multiple thread, or a single thread which uses the `select` syscall. This syscall is given a set of file descriptors and return the list of descriptors where something can be read of written.

Whatever the way terminals are implemented, you will have as many shell (or other program) processes as opened terminals. If you launch 10 Python script, you will have 10 independent processes. Each may have a Global interpreter lock but they are per process locks. (Acquiring a lock in one process won’t stop other processes to acquire its GIL).

Comment: Is a process here not referring to a CPU core? If so, then will I not be able to run more than 8 terminals with python, since 8 is the maximum number of cores my CPU has?

Comment: Any modern OS can handle more processes than the core numbers. But if you have more running processes than CPU cores, some processes will run on a core and other process will wait to be scheduled on a CPU. The OS switch the process regularly to make each process having a fair part of the CPU.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer An old multi-process OS certainly can, too, because it was forced to run on single cores! (-;

Comment: Yes, surely… preemptive multi-process OS are not a new thing. But there were an era where some OS had no multitasking feature or a cooperative multitasking feature.